# Two subsequences, can we make them have the same indexing?

Tags: sequences-and-series

Suppose we have two subsequences $n_j$ and $n_k$ such that
$$u_{n_j} \to u$$ and
$$v_{n_k} \to v.$$

Is it possible to find a single sequence of numbers $n_l$ such that
$$u_{n_l} \to u$$ and
$$v_{n_l} \to v.$$

Is it as simple as taking $n_l$ to be the sequence formed by taking the union of $n_j$ and $n_k$?

Comment: No. Several no's, in fact. No, you can't find that single sequence. The _intersection_ would work except the intersection may not be a sequence. And no, when you talk about $n_j$ and $n_k$ you're actually talking about only _one_ sequence! If you want to talk about two sequences of integers call one $n_j$ and the other $m_j$. Or something

Comment: In general, no. By saying "subsequence", I assume you have an underlying sequence $\{a_n\}$ from which the two subsequences were drawn. If $a_n = (-1)^n$, then $a_{2n} \to 1$ and $a_{2n + 1} \to -1$, but there is no way find a single sequence to achieve what you want. More generally, if you may do so, then $u$ and $v$ must be identical.

Comment: On the positive side, if you form the  sequence of vectors $\{(u_n,v_n)\}_{n=1}^{\infty}$, and if you assume this sequence is in some compact subset of $\mathbb{R}^N$, then Bolzano-Weirstrass says there is a subsequence $n[k]$ for which $\lim_{k\rightarrow\infty} (u_{n[k]}, v_{n[k]})  = (u^*, v^*)$ for some vectors $u^*$, $v^*$ (perhaps not the same as the vectors $u$ and $v$ that you want).  Also, if you want, you can do it so that you make the first vector $u^*$ the same as your desired $u$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Ok, suppose we have $|u_n|_{L^2} < C$ and $|\nabla u_n|_{L^2} < C$ uniformly. Then for a subsequence $u_{n_a} \to_w u$ in $L^2$ and $\nabla u_{n_b} \to_w \nabla u$. Then why can we say that there is a sequence $n_j$ such that $u_{n_j} \to_w u$ in $H^1$? Isn't this the same problem?

Comment: @Zhanxiong Thanks, please see my above comment.

Comment: @Michael Thanks but I am working in general normed space. Pls see my above comment.

Comment: Same thing as long as your space has a compactness property. But: Lots of notation in your last comment that is not clear to me:  What is meant by the gradient of a sequence?  Gradient with respect to what? What is meant by convergence with a "w" over the arrow? What is meant by the $L_2$ subscript on $|u_n|$?

Comment: @EasyStarter First, you really do have to fix the notation! The notations $n_j$, $n_k$, $n_a$ and $n_b$ all refer to the same sequence. Think about it. What does the notation $(n_j)$ denote? The sequence $(n_1,n_2,\dots)$. The notation $(n_k)$ also refers to the sequence $(n_1, n_2, \dots)$. Exactly the same thing. Now, $(n_j)$ and $(m_j)$ are two different sequences: the first is $(n_1,\dots)$ and the second is $(m_1,\dots)$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Hmm ok, I think I should use $g(n)$ for a function $g$ to denote subsequence. it is confusing.

Comment: @Michael I think I should think a bit more about it first.

Comment: @EasyStarter Ok, for your question: This is the question you should have asked to begin with. You can't pick a subsequence where the functions converge and another subsequence where the derivatives converge and jam them together somehow. But you _can_ do this: Pick a subsequence $(n_j)$ such that the functions converge, and _then_ find a sub-subsequence $(n_{j_k})$ where the derivatives converge. So they both converge on that sub-subsequence. Which is what you wanted, right?

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Oh i see. so what you mean is: by the bound on the functions, there is a subsequence $u_{g(n)} \to_w u$. since $u_n'$ is bounded, also $u_{g_n}'$ is bounded, so a subsequence $u_{f(g(n))}' \to_w u'$. Then we pick the subseuqnece $f(g(n))$ to get what I wanted.

Comment: @EasyStarter Using functional notation for subsequences is confusing maybe, but it may also clarify things. What it clarifies is this: a sequence is a certain _function_ (with domain the natural numbers); a subsequence is the _composition_ of two such functions. Quiz: A second ago when I wrote $n_{j_k}$, did that mean $(n_j)_k$ or $n_{(j_k)}$?

Comment: Yes, except the second is $g(f(n))$, not $f(g(n))$.

Comment: If I am right you meant the former!!!

Comment: @EasyStarter I knew you were going to say that when I saw the $f(g(n))$. It's the latter. When I write $n_j$ that's shorthand for a function named $n$, such that $n(j)=n_j$. Now a subsequence is supposed to pick out just some of the $n_j$. The index here is $j$, while $n$ is not the index, $n$ is just the name of our function. So if I said $f(n_j)$ that would not be a subsequence. I want to choose some of the $j$'s. Say I want to keep $j_1,j_2,\dots$. That's a sequence $(j_k)$. So my subsequence is $n_j$ with $j$ replaced by $j_k$; the latter. In functional notation it's $n\circ j$.

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Thanks for explaining. I think  it's easier to use $g$ and $f$ for me!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $u_n = v_n = (-1)^{n}$. Then $u_{2n}\to 1$, and $v_{2n+1}\to -1$. And there is no way to find a common subsequence $\{n_k\}$ such that $u_{n_k}\to 1$ and $v_{n_k}\to -1$.